# Getting nullpointer exception for t1.x why?

Tags: java

```
`class test {
        int x = 10, y = 5;
        public static test t1 = new test();

        {
            System.out.println("NSB");
            System.out.println(t1.x);
            System.out.println(t1.y);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("C main");

        }

    }`
```

Answer (score 3):

Because the initialization block is executed before the constructor runs, and before the assignment to `t1` is made.

So basically, this is executed first : `new test()`  That invokes the constructor.  Just before that constructor runs, the initialization block runs.  That block dereferences `test.t1`, but no assignment has been made yet.

Thus, <s>Calvinism</s> NPE.

Comment: what do you mean by dereference. Could you please elaborate on that point? When the Constructor is invoked ideally there should be memory allocated for both x and y right?

Comment: "Deference" means to use a reference.  `t1` is a reference to the object you are creating, and when you access it by `t1.x` you deference `t1`.  It's `t1` that's the problem here, not `x`.  Yes memory is allocated for `x` and `y`, but the `t1` has not been assigned yet (the `=` hasn't been executed yet) because you're still in the constructor (in other words `new` hasn't finished yet).